# Page inside another page

Tags: javascript, html

When i click [Wikimapia's](http://wikimapia.org/) objects, the page shows object's info to me. How do i load a page inside another page like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could either load the response from an ajax call inside a div or use an iframe.  It looks like wikimapia itself uses an iframe wrapped inside a div.

```
<style>
#iframe_wrapper{
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-150px;
}
</style>
<div id='iframe_wrapper'>
    <iframe src='http://www.google.com'></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: but how does it become draggable over the main page and seem like a new window while still being a part of the main page?

Comment: I mean, i understand how to make something like this: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxcontent.htm , but that's not what i want.

Comment: Looking at their code more closely it does look like they're using an iframe (updated in answer) that is wrapped in a div.  An iframe is literally a webpage inside another webpage.  The look is all achieved through CSS.  You would set the position of the wrapper div to absolute and use top/left to place it where you want.  I don't see any way to move the box around but it can be done using jqueryui's draggable method.

Comment: Hmm... i thought it was something more simple. Mainly because ive seen lots of such things here and there.

Comment: Its simple to do technically.  I posted an example in the answer.

Comment: Ive got how they do it and made a page like that (more simple version). Thank you for ideas.